# A problem about matrix/vector extension via ArrayPad

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector

Given that I have a vector and matrix as follow:

```
vec = Array[Subscript["P", #] &, 6, 0];
mat = Array[Subscript["P", #1, #2] &, {5, 4}, {0, 0}];
```

And I could use the *built-in* `ArrayPad[]` to achieve the below style:

```
ArrayPad[vec , 1, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm
ArrayPad[mat, 1, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

However, when the $P_i$ or $P_{i,j}$ is a coordinate of 2D and 3D point, respesctively, this method will in fail.

For instance,

```
vec1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
ArrayPad[vec1, 1, "Fixed"]

(* {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, 3}, 
    {3, 3, -1, -1}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 0, 0}}*)
```

In fact, I need

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}, {5,0}}
```

rather than

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, 3}, 
 {3, 3, -1, -1}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 0, 0}}
```

An alternative method that I could figure out is using `Hold[]` and `ReleaseHold[]`.

```
vec2 = Hold/@{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
ArrayPad[vec2, 1, "Fixed"] // ReleaseHold
(*{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}, {5, 0}}*)

mat2 = 
  {{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}}, 
   {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, -1}, {2,3, 1}}, 
   {{3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}}, 
   {{4, 1, 1}, {4, 2, -1}, {4, 3, 0}}};
ArrayPad[Map[Hold, mat2, {2}], 1, "Fixed"] // ReleaseHold

ArrayPad[Map[Hold, mat2, {2}], 1, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm
(*
{{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 1}}, 
 {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 1}}, 
 {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, -1}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1}}, 
 {{3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 3, -1}}, 
 {{4, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 1}, {4, 2, -1}, {4, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 0}}, 
 {{4, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 1}, {4, 2, -1}, {4, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 0}}}
*)
```

[image]

---

So my question is how to achieve the **right extension** of matrix/vector using `ArrayPad[...,"Fixed"]` or other good solution.

Comment: Try e.g. `ArrayPad[vec1, {1}, "Fixed"]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch En, how about understand this usage `{1}`, and how to extend this to matrix?

Comment: please see my edited answer. it also works for matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vec1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
ArrayPad[vec1, {1}, "Fixed"]

(* {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}, {5, 0}}  *)
```

or

```
ArrayPad[vec1, {{1, 1}}, "Fixed"]
```

which is more in keeping with the docs. For matrices:

```
mat2 = {{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, -1}, {2,
      3, 1}}, {{3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}}, {{4, 1, 1}, {4, 
     2, -1}, {4, 3, 0}}};
ArrayPad[mat2, {{1}, {1}}, "Fixed"]
```

or

```
ArrayPad[mat2, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, "Fixed"]
```

which seems to be more consistent with the docs (on my reading of them anyway).

[image]

For the matrix, according the the question, you want to pad on both ends and both sides, therefore you need to use 2 specifications. On top of that you need to use lists due to the extra level relative to vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Mike's answer, the relevant part of the help for `ArrayPad[]` says

> > $\tt ArrayPad$[`array`,{{$m_1$ , $n_1$},{$m_2$ , $n_2$},…},…] pads with $m_i$, $n_i$ elements at level $i$ in `array`.

So when you don't give the padding in the form of a list it applies that padding to every single level specification.

Since your array has $3$ levels, there are three different ways you could pad $1$ element to a single level,

```
{ArrayPad[mat2, 1, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm,
 ArrayPad[mat2, {{1}, {0}, {0}}, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm,
 ArrayPad[mat2, {{0}, {1}, {0}}, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm,
 ArrayPad[mat2, {{0}, {0}, {1}}, "Fixed"] // MatrixForm}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation:)